# C# need to use enter key in multiline texbox to move down one line, not leave the texbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, multiline

In C# I have a multiline `TextBox` that users enter case notes into. However, when they enter the text box and hit the Enter key, it leaves the text box and jumps to the next field like the tab button. Is there any way to override this behavior and make the return key move down a line? I don't need to disable the return key behavior on the entire form, only in the one multiline text box.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the property

```
 textBox.AcceptsReturn = true;
```

Without this property you could use `CTRL+ENTER` to initiate a newline.
Sometimes this is useful if you need to have a default AcceptButton also set on the form.

[See MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: OMG. thats it? i feel so ashamed! lol. I will mark this answered when it lets me. Thanks for the fast reply and the blow to my ego. haha

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`AcceptsReturn` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx) to true.